# How do I get a value of another table on Laravel?

Tags: laravel, controller

I'm trying to get just value of id column on a table but it returns

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '[{"id":1}]' for column 'id_jenis' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `pesanan` (`name`, `telpon`, `alamat`, `id_jenis`, `jenis`, `do`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Pradita Candrani, 0813, Jalan Sunan Ampel Kasin, [{"id":1}], Cuci Basah Standar, None, 2019-11-27 12:18:35, 2019-11-27 12:18:35))
```

Here it is my code on Controller

```
public function pesan(Request $request){
    $harga = Harga::select('id')->where('nama',$request->jenis)->get();
    Pesanan::create([
        'name' => $request->nama,
        'telpon' => $request->telpon,
        'alamat' => $request->alamat,
        'id_jenis' => $harga,
        'jenis' => $request->jenis,
        'do'=>$request->do
]);
return redirect('/pesanan');
}
```

how can I fix this? Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting object now and passing it to  `id_jenis` directly. use `first()` instead of `get()`. and pass the `$harga->id` in `id_jenis`.

```
    $harga = Harga::select('id')->where('nama',$request->jenis)->first();
    Pesanan::create([
        'name' => $request->nama,
        'telpon' => $request->telpon,
        'alamat' => $request->alamat,
        'id_jenis' => $harga->id,
        'jenis' => $request->jenis,
        'do'=>$request->do
]);
```

If you want to store multiple ids in `id_jenis` then use pluck.

```
$harga = Harga::where('nama',$request->jenis)->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

Here you'll get multiple ids in array. so use `json_encode` to store JSON in db as below.

```
    Pesanan::create([
        'name' => $request->nama,
        'telpon' => $request->telpon,
        'alamat' => $request->alamat,
        'id_jenis' => json_encode($harga),
        'jenis' => $request->jenis,
        'do'=>$request->do
]);
```

Comment: Select the answer if helped.

Answer (score 0):

`$harga = Harga::select('id')->where('nama',$request->jenis)->get();`

After this line, write

`\Log::info(['Harga', $harga]);`

and check the latest file and error in `/storage/logs/laravel.log`

Welcome to the wonderful world of debugging